# Instruction on how to build Qt for VxWorks?

Tags: qt, installation, vxworks

I would like to use Qt with VxWorks. Is that possible? If so, does anyone know if there's a tutorial or step-by-step guide on how to do so?

**Extra**
If anyone has experience in using Qt with VxWorks, you could share here as well.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you already seen this page:

[Platform Notes - VxWorks](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6-snapshot/platform-notes-vxworks.html)

> This page contains information about
>   the Qt for VxWorks port. More
>   information about the combinations of
>   platforms and compilers supported by
>   Qt can be found on the Supported
>   Platforms page.
>
> - Supported Versions
> - Limitations
> - Build Instructions
> - General Notes

hope this helps, regards